# Get the SRID of a geometry field

Tags: postgis

I have a table with some geometry types in and need to be able to return the SRID of a given field. How can I do this. I have had a search but all I can find is the function to alter a SRID. In Oracle I am doing this:

```
A.CLUSTER_EXTENT.SDO_SRID
```

Is there an equivalent function in PostGIS?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[ST_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html) will give you the SRID of a single geometry.
Use [Find_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html) for getting the SRID of a column.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why I havent been able to find that.

Answer (score -2):

Figure out SRID of the data

You will notice one of the files it extracts is called `TOWNS_POLY.prj`. A `.prj` is often included with ESRI shape files and tells you the projection of the data. We'll need to match this descriptive projection to an SRID (the id field of a spatial ref record in the spatial_ref_sys table) if we ever want to reproject our data. 
Open up the .prj file in a text editor. You'll see something like `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001` and `UNIT["Meter",1.0]`

Open up your PgAdmin III query tool and type in the following statement

```
select srid, srtext, proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srtext ILIKE '%Massachusetts%'
```

And then click the green arrow. This will bring up about 10 records.
Note the srid of the closest match. In this case its 26986.

**NOTE:** srid is not just a PostGIS term. It is an OGC standard so you will see SRID mentioned a lot in other spatial databases, gis webservices and applications. Most of the common spatial reference systems have globally defined numbers. So 26986 always maps to NAD83_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001 Meters. Most if not all MassGIS data is in this particular projection.

[Source](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01)